# Render table based on datazoom in echarts4r

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

I have a table in a `shiny` app that is filtered depending on the `input$brush` on a graph made in ggplot. So the user brushes over on some points in the chart and gets the corresponding table below. All this is working:

```
  output$plot_brushed_points <- render_gt({
    dat<-dft()%>%
      select(c(4,8:16,18:19,21:38))
    dat<-dat %>% 
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !(c("ODDS1","ODDS2","ODDS3")), ~ round(.x, 3)))
    res<- brushedPoints(dat,input$brush)
    gt(res) %>% 
      opt_interactive() %>% 
      tab_header(md("**In-depth parameter details**")) %>% 
          tab_options(table.width = pct(100),
                      container.width = pct(150))
  })
```

I'm switching all my graphs to echarts and thus I need to keep the same feature. I would like to get a table from the points filtered on the graph with. I'm assuming I need to get some coordinates from `e_datazoom()` but couldn't figure how to make it work.
Here is the code of my graph:

```
output$plotui1<- renderEcharts4r({
  g1<- dft() %>%
    select(x=xvar(),y=yvar(),sz=sz(),FSCORE, HOME,AWAY) %>%
    group_by(FSCORE) %>%
    mutate(game=paste(HOME,AWAY,sep="-")) %>% 
    e_charts(x) %>%
    e_scatter(y,sz,bind = game,symbol_size = 2) %>%
    e_tooltip(formatter=htmlwidgets::JS("
           function(params){
           var vals = params.name.split('-')
          return('<strong>' + vals[0] + '-'+ vals[1] +
         '</strong><br />xvar(): ' + params.value[0] + '<br />yvar(): ' + params.value[1] +
         '<br />sz():' +params.value[2]) 
      }")) %>% 
    e_datazoom()  %>% 
    e_zoom(
      dataZoomIndex = 1
    ) %>% 
    e_legend(bottom = 0)
    g1
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way.

It is possible with JavaScript to get the percentage of the zoom start position and the percentage of the zoom end position. They are given by the `datazoom` event. It is also possible to get the range of the x-axis. So one can get the min x-value and the max x-value of the zoomed region. And send them to Shiny with `Shiny.setInputValue`.

But when you drag a zoom handle, the `datazoom` event is continuously triggered. This is very fast, so I use `debounce` in the Shiny app to slow down the reception of the min and max values.

```r
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use onRender()

myChart <- USArrests |>
  e_charts(UrbanPop) |>
  e_line(Assault) |>
  e_grid() |>
  e_datazoom() |>
  onRender(
    "function(el, x) {
       var chart = this.getChart();
       chart.on('datazoom', function(e) {
         var xbounds = chart.getModel().getComponent('xAxis', 0).axis.scale.getExtent();
         var xmin = xbounds[0];
         var xmax = xbounds[1];
         var xrange = xmax - xmin;
         var min = xmin + xrange * e.start/100;
         var max = xmax - xrange * (100 - e.end)/100;
         Shiny.setInputValue('zoomBounds', [min, max]);
       });
    }")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      7,
      echarts4rOutput("echart")
    ),
    column(
      5,
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$echart <- renderEcharts4r({
    myChart
  })

  zoomBounds <- reactive({
    input$zoomBounds
  }) |> debounce(1000) # use debounce to slow down

  zoomedData <- reactive({
    bounds <- zoomBounds()
    if(is.null(bounds)) { # initial state
      return(USArrests)
    }
    xmin <- bounds[1]
    xmax <- bounds[2]
    subset(USArrests, UrbanPop >= xmin & UrbanPop <= xmax)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    zoomedData()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit: correction

I misunderstood a point. This is easier actually, as there's no need of the zoom percentage positions. So use this JS code instead:

```r
  onRender(
    "function(el, x) {
       var chart = this.getChart();
       chart.on('datazoom', function(e) {
         var xbounds = chart.getModel().getComponent('xAxis', 0).axis.scale.getExtent();
         Shiny.setInputValue('zoomBounds', xbounds);
       });
    }")
```

[image]